# html-like select in silverlight for windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to have something like what in HTML would be

```
<select>
  <option>1. option</option>
  <option>2. option</option>
</select>
```

is there a possibility in silverlight to so so?

thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `ComboBox` in Windows Phone 7. You need to install [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) for this. It contains `ListPicker`. More info about it you can find [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the ComboBox?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As Ku6opr pointed out, this control is not available out of the box for Windows Phone 7. You will need to look at his answer for the link to the Silverlight Toolkit.